# rsync fails when ssh can't open /dev/tty

Tags: ssh, rsync, docker

I've got a script that needs to rsync some files to a remote machine. The rsync command looks like this:

```
rsync -avz -e 'ssh -vv -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i /data/credentials/rsync2.key' \
   --rsync-path="mkdir -p ~/new_data/12345/ && rsync" \
   /data/new_data/  some_user@$REMOTE_HOST_IP:~/new_data/12345/
```

The output from the script looks like:

```
...
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 134/256
debug2: bits set: 505/1024
debug1: Server host key: RSA XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Host key verification failed.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]
```

It looks to me like ssh is trying to use a passphrase on the key. It shouldn't, the key doesn't require a passphrase. Also, I'm pretty sure that the message about `/dev/tty` is not entirely accurate since my script confirms that `/dev/tty` exists (`ls -l` on it shows: `crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 5, 0 Feb 23 19:37 /dev/tty`). I also know the keyfile is valid since I can manually connect to the remote host via ssh using the key.

The one catch here is that my script is running within a docker container and I'm not sure how that may affect rsync and ssh.

Comment: What happens when you try to `ssh -vv -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i /data/credentials/rsync2.key some_user@$REMOTE_HOST_IP` by itself without the context of `rsync`?

Comment: Looks like a wrong key format. How did you get/create the key?

Comment: @DopeGhoti: Same result, minus the rsync error. When I execute the command *outside* of a docker context, it works fine.

Comment: You could try passing the `-T` argument to your `ssh` command, which will disable tty allocation.